# How to draw in QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyside

I try to draw in QTableWidget, but I can't find appropriate method, I can add a label widget in to QTableWidgetItem, but can't connect them.

The effect now:

[image]

The effect I need:

[image]

How can I draw like effect I need, I need some methods...

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/12707/solved-modify-qtablewidget-s-paintevent